# Passing user authentication details from one server to the next

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, certificate, pki

I've got users authenticating with client certificates in a JBoss server. All fine.

If I then use Apache HTTPClient to call onto another server it sends the client certificate of the user JBoss is configured with. I'd like to be able to pass the client certificate through so the second server authenticates the calling user too.

Is this possible (I'm assuming not as the server won't have the private key of the client certificate) and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty convinced from RFC5246 [1] that it's not possible.

*If the client has sent
a certificate with signing ability, a digitally-signed
CertificateVerify message is sent to explicitly verify possession of
the private key in the certificate.*

After all, what's the point of a private key if you make it public? I'll just get the server I'm connecting to to give my system user increased privileges.

1 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.  The certificate is merely a *public* identifier of who the user is.  The actual authentication is done using the client's *private key*.  As a result, you would need to obtain both the certificate AND private key to accomplish this, which would eliminate all of the security around the use of certificates in the first place.  Certificates are considered public, and can be distributed wherever needed to allow for identity verification, digital signature validation, encryption, etc.  The private key must, by definition, remain private in order to ensure the security of the credential.

To accomplish your goal of propagating identity information, there are other tools you can use.  If your JBoss server(s) are all part of the same security domain, you can use JavaEE Security to propagate the identity information.  With some creative coding, you may also be able to use Kerberos to propagate the identity, although that is a non-trivial amount of effort.